# Javascript regex function wont initiate

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to perform some validation using regular expressions in Javascript.

8 out of 10 of my regex validations work like a charm except this one, I have tried many changes in my regex and code, ran in firebug, dreamweaver, multiple browsers, the code will not alert, the problem lies in the function and i cannot point my finer on it.

here is a testing version of my code:

```
function validate_DOB()
    {
        var regexDOB = /^(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)([0-9]){4}$/i;
        var checkDOB = "jan1888";//document.form.DateofBirth.value;

        if (regexDOB.test(checkDOB) == false)
            {
                alert("Date of birth must be in the following format: jan1990(example)");
                //document.form.DateofBirth.focus();
                return false;
            }

        else if (2014 - eval(checkDOB.substr(3,4))  < 19)
            {
                alert("You must be at least 19 years of age");
                //document.form.DateofBirth.focus();
                return false;
            }

        else
        {

            alert("true");
            return true;

        }}// validate DOB

validate_DOB();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: No response, nothing will alert in the browser, thank you.

Comment: I tried this on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qXfLm/ it is giving me alert

Comment: Thats an alert I never got on scratchpad/dreamweaver/browsers, its a false alert nonetheless, if you are born in 1888 you are older than 19.

Comment: sorry but still i didn't understand your problem

Comment: really thankful for your help, but my problem is, when my code reaches this function everything stops and i get no response, its an if/else condition, I must get an alert, but i do not.

Comment: If you expect the alert "true" you will never get it, as it's after the return

Comment: yes i realized, thank you, however this is only testing code, and alert("true") is not there in my code and shouldnt be there, i fixed it and still wont work

Comment: if you are looking for else alert("true") just move this line before return true

Comment: Can you check firefox firebug console and check what is the actual error

Comment: no error whatsoever, simply no alert in case of true or false submission.

Comment: after a few modifications, i got it to work in scratchpad, however it still wont alert in the browser, and dreamweaver.

Comment: Try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/qXfLm/3/

Comment: clearly there is no error in you above code, can you post your original code?